# Install OpenCL/Pyopencl on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, opencl

There are a lot of instructions on how to get OpenCL running on Ubuntu, but all of them are outdated (>4 years) or simply not working.

Is there any current, working tutorial on how to get open CL running on Ubuntu (14.04 or 15.04)?

I tried to follow [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/opencl/topic/390630#comment-1832283) instruction but I wonder if it's best practice to install from a converted *rpm as it seems to be kind of a hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to code on your CPU/GPU the AMD guide is probably a good place to start. To get the OpenCL drivers working on a computer with an AMD APU/GPU you simply need to install the fglrx driver from the software center. To test that its working and to write code you may also want the AMD APP SDK.

I used version 3.0 of the SDK from the [AMD site](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/).
The install guide is [here](http://amd-dev.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/AMD_APP_SDK_InstallationNotes.pdf).
Once you have it you can follow their [programming guide](http://amd-dev.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wordpress/media/2013/12/AMD_OpenCL_Programming_User_Guide2.pdf).

Here is one of the early examples modified to simply print out the number of compute units on your machines GPU:

```
            //
            // Copyright (c) 2010 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. All rights reserved.
            // Modified by Aedazan for learning purposes.
            // Uploaded as fair use teaching material 17 U.S. Code § 107.
            // A minimalist OpenCL program.
            #include <CL/cl.h>
            #include <stdio.h>

            #define NWITEMS 512


            // A simple memset kernel

            //const char *source = "__kernel void memset( __global uint *dst ) \n" "{ \n" " dst[get_global_id(0)] = get_global_id(0);  \n" "} \n";
            const char *source = "__kernel void memset( __global uint *dst ) " "{ " " dst[get_global_id(0)] = get_global_id(0)*get_global_id(0);" 
            ""
            "\n" "} \n";


            int main(int argc, char ** argv)
            {
            // 1. Get a platform.
            cl_platform_id platform;
            clGetPlatformIDs( 1, &platform, NULL );
            // 2. Find a gpu device.
            cl_device_id device;
            cl_uint compute_units;
            clGetDeviceIDs( platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU,1,&device,NULL);
            clGetDeviceInfo( device, CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS, sizeof(cl_uint), &compute_units, NULL);
            printf("Compute units: %d\n", compute_units);

            // 3. Create a context and command queue on that device.
            cl_context context = clCreateContext( NULL, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            cl_command_queue queue = clCreateCommandQueue( context, device, 0, NULL );
            // 4. Perform runtime source compilation, and obtain kernel entry point.
            cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource( context, 1, &source, NULL, NULL );
            clBuildProgram( program, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, NULL );
            cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel( program, "memset", NULL );
            // 5. Create a data buffer.
            cl_mem buffer = clCreateBuffer( context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, NWITEMS * sizeof(cl_uint), NULL, NULL );

            // 6. Launch the kernel. Let OpenCL pick the local work size.
            size_t global_work_size = NWITEMS;
            clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(buffer), (void*) &buffer);
            clEnqueueNDRangeKernel( queue,
            kernel,
            1,
            NULL,
            &global_work_size,
            NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
            clFinish( queue );
            // 7. Look at the results via synchronous buffer map.
            cl_uint *ptr;
            ptr = (cl_uint *) clEnqueueMapBuffer( queue, buffer, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ, 0, NWITEMS * sizeof(cl_uint), 0, NULL, NULL, NULL );
            int i;
            for(i=0; i < NWITEMS; i++)
            //printf("%d %d\n", i, ptr[i]);
            return 0;
            }
```

You can compile it with the following line. It assumes you installed the SDK as root into the default locations.

```
gcc -o computec.bin -I /opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/include/ -L /opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64/ test.c -lOpenCL
```

Answer (score 0):

We've updated our [article](http://streamcomputing.eu/blog/2011-06-24/install-opencl-on-debianubuntu-orderly/) yearly, so it should be still working. Yes, you should "alien" the rpm to get it on Ubuntu.

Comment: I tried that one, but failed at the conversion step. I found some intel *.pub key that is mentioned on the intel homepage, but I have no idea how to get that to work with alien? 
My warning is:

warning: opencl-1.2-base-4.5.0.8-1.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID f789186f: NOKEY

Comment: I found out, that you have to add the public keys into rpm database. Still the remaining error: 'Warning: Skipping conversion of scripts in package opencl-1.2-base: postinst prerm
Warning: Use the --scripts parameter to include the scripts.
Package build failed; could not run generated debian/rules file.
 (in cleanup) unable to delete temporary directory 'opencl-1.2-base-4.5.0.8': Keine Berechtigung at /usr/share/perl5/Alien/Package.pm line 349, <GETPERMS> line 6.
'